# How to print files with the name of current directory instead of full path

Tags: windows, windows-shell

`dir /b /s`

This prints:
`D:\stuff\tmp>dir /b /s
D:\stuff\tmp\A.java
D:\stuff\tmp\AAA
D:\stuff\tmp\B.java
D:\stuff\tmp\C.java
D:\stuff\tmp\Why.class
D:\stuff\tmp\Why.java
D:\stuff\tmp\XX.class
D:\stuff\tmp\XX.java
D:\stuff\tmp\XX.txt
D:\stuff\tmp\AAA\aaa.kkk`

I need to print:
`D:\stuff\tmp>????
tmp\A.java
tmp\AAA
tmp\B.java
tmp\C.java
tmp\Why.class
tmp\Why.java
tmp\XX.class
tmp\XX.java
tmp\XX.txt
tmp\AAA\aaa.kkk`

How can I do that?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I found this: [TechNet DIR Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121.aspx). I don't have time to review it, but it should say whether you can do it or not.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, if you put the following in a CMD file:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`cmd /c dir /s /b`) DO (
  set NAME=%%A
  set SHORT=!NAME:%cd%\=!
  echo.!SHORT!
)
```

It takes the output of your original `dir` command and uses string substitution to remove the current directory.  See `set /?` for more information on this.  If you prefer to pass the directory as an argument instead of using the current directory, try this modification of the variables:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`cmd /c dir /s /b %1`) DO (
  set NAME=%%A
  set SHORT=!NAME:%~1\=!
  echo.!SHORT!
)
```

Beware of filenames and directories which have an exclamation mark in the filename, as they tend to get stripped out with this method.  If you need something more robust which can handle this, look into installing GNU [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) or [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).  You can also investigate using the GNU [find](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) command if you don't mind the filenames coming back UNIX style with slashes instead of backslashes, and a leading `./` in front of each entry.

There is also another answer which may give you ideas on handling exclamation marks in CMD processing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873578/how-to-read-a-string-with-from-a-file-in-windows-batch-script/32874195#32874195